# Jest cannot find module Vue/Vite

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

Jest Configuration:

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'vue'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  testMatch: ['**/tests/unit/**/*.[jt]s?(x)'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest',
  },
}
```

My test file (.ts file) :

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/vue'
import Kaki from '~/components/Kaki.vue'

test('Kaki.vue', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(Kaki)
  getByText('Tono')
})
```

Here's my directory structure:

[image: Directory Structure]

When I run the test, it says `Cannot find module '~/components/Kaki.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.`

I think it has something to do with `moduleNameMapper`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check if it works if you change your `Index.spec.ts` to a `.js` file? The error you're getting is because TypeScript doesn't know what type should `.vue` files have.

In a new Vue CLI project, the error you're getting is prevented with the `shims.d.ts` which tells TS to treat `*.vue` files as if their default export had the `Vue` type.

The "correct" solution here is to figure out why isn't `shims.d.ts` telling TypeScript the type for *.vue files (which is why you're getting the "Cannot find module [...] or its corresponding **type declarations**" error

Another thing is - this is not a real solution but a temporary fix:

```
// @ts-ignore
import Kaki from '~/components/Kaki.vue'
```

Another thing you could try is importing Kaki with a relative path (so without the ~ alias)? The ~ alias may be broken in some way - are you sure the alias is correctly defined in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: I did try to use relative but it's still broken, so the solution was actually the `shims.d.ts`. I tried to recreate [this template](https://github.com/DiegoFT/vue3-vite-template/blob/main/src/types/shims-vue.d.ts) but forgot the declaration file. Thanks man

Comment: Hi, I've tried @ts-ignore and it worked, thank you. But I have also shims.d.ts file. Still don't understand why ts-ignore needed. Do you have any idea? I've also explained my problem here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70983053/vue3-jest-module-not-found-error-while-using-store)